# Hibernate: mapping map exception

Tags: java, hibernate

I try to map one-2-many relationship via `Map` interface.

**Problem:** I got a weird exception

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at ...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "Order"
```

**SQL query which cause rhe exception: (show_sql=true)**

```
Hibernate: insert into Order (customer_id, number, id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Session createSession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    createSession.beginTransaction();

    final Customer customer = new Customer();
    Map<String, Order> orders = new HashMap<String, Order>() {{
        put("one", new Order("one", customer));
        put("two", new Order("two", customer));
        put("three", new Order("three", customer));
    }};
    customer.setOrders(orders);
    for (Order order : orders.values())
        createSession.save(order);
    createSession.save(customer);

    createSession.getTransaction().commit(); //HERE THE EXCEPTION COMES
    createSession.close();
}
```

*Entities:*

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    @MapKey(name = "number")
    private Map<String, Order> orders;

    // + getters & setters
}

@Entity
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String number;

    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;

    //+ Constructors, getters & setters
}
```

Comment: Is that query generated by the hibernate or is your own query ? You need not pass the id as it is auto generated.

Comment: @Jay this query is generated by Hibernate.

Comment: Why are you saving both customer & order ? createSession.save(order); and createSession.save(customer); Just save any one and use Cascade all, that would save all the related objects.

Comment: How does your configuration file looks like ? Have you configured the dialect ? like org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but I remember getting this error when I was trying to query a table that didn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code:

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
Session createSession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
createSession.beginTransaction();

final Customer customer = new Customer();
Map<String, Order> orders = new HashMap<String, Order>() {{
    put("one", new Order("one", customer));
    put("two", new Order("two", customer));
    put("three", new Order("three", customer));
}};

for (Order order : orders.values())
    order.setCustomer(customer);

customer.setOrders(orders);
createSession.save(customer);

createSession.getTransaction().commit(); //HERE THE EXCEPTION COMES
createSession.close();
```

}